Do elliptic K3 surfaces have line bundle of relative degree $1$?
Let $f:S\to \mathbb P^1$ be an elliptic K3 surface ($S$ is a compact Kähler manifold or projective, if this makes things easier). If $f$ admits a section $C \subset S$, then the line bundle $\mathcal O(C)$ has degree one on each fiber $F = f^{-1}(p)$.
I was wondering if one can always find such a line bundle $L \in \operatorname{Pic}(S)$, such that $L|_F$ has degree one for each fiber $F$, even if $f$ does not admit a section?

Alternatively to Sasha's argument, such an $L$ gives a divisor of degree 1 on the generic fibre. By Riemann--Roch one then gets a rational point on the generic fibre, i.e. a rational section, which again extends to a regular section.

@LazzaroCampeotti Thanks for your suggestion. But don't we have to base-change the generic fiber to the algebraic closure $\overline{k(t)}$ to apply Riemann-Roch, so that the rational section only exists over $\overline{k(t)}$?

Riemann--Roch is true for (nice) curves over an arbitrary field, for example according to Poonen, "Rational Points on Varieties", Theorem 2.5.3.

@LazzaroCampeotti Interesting, I wasn't aware of that. Thanks for the reference!

The existence of $L$ of relative degree 1 is in fact equivalent to the existence of a section. Indeed, the pushforward $f_*L$ is a line bundle on $\mathbb{P}^1$ and the zero locus of the adjunction morphism
$$
f^*f_*L \to L
$$
provides a rational section of $f$. Removing all vertical components (if there are any), one obtains a regular section.

Thanks for your answer. Just to make sure I get the details right: $f_* L$ is a line bundle by an application of Cohomology and Base Change. If one restricts the adjunction morphism to a smooth fiber $F$ it becomes $$H^0(L|_F) \mathcal O_F \to L|_F$$ whose cokernel is supported on a single point (as $\operatorname{deg} L|_F = 1$). Correct?

Yes, that's right.
